# how to get data from flask individually from each country using an API

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

This is the project so far: http://oussama1997.pythonanywhere.com/

Here is the Flask-Python code:

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, session
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)


country = 'Morocco'

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route("/covid", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        global country
        new_country = request.form.get('country')
        country = new_country


    url = "https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries/{}"

    
    r = requests.get(url.format(country)).json()

    covid = {
                'country': country.upper(),
                'confirmed': r['cases'],
                'recovered': r['recovered'],
                'critical': r['critical'],
                'deaths': r['deaths'],
                'todayCases': r['todayCases'],
                'todayDeaths': r['todayDeaths'],
                'active': r['active'],
                'totalTests': r['totalTests'],
            }
    
    print(covid)

    return render_template("index.html", covid=covid)


@app.route("/protect")
def protect():
    return render_template("protect.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

now in html I want to make the news ticker but I don't know how to get information from each country individually, for example:

USA: 5498464 | Canada: 5465465 | Spain: 5465654 | Germany: 8765165...

thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well currently you are asking the api for data about a given country. This api provides a method for pulling data for all countries which is a GET request to:

```
https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries
```

Using that, you can iterate over the response to build out your desired output like:

```
r = requests.get('https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries').json()
for country_data in r
    print(country_data.country, country_data.cases)
```

- [COVID19 API documentation](https://github.com/javieraviles/covidAPI)

Comment: I tried doing this to go through all the data but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong:
url = "https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries"

 response = requests.get(url).json()

 i = range(0, 10)

 all = {
  'country': response[i]['country'],
  'confirmed': response[i]['cases'],
 }



 for i in all:
  print(all)